# Android AVD cannot connect to internet

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

My Android emulators cannot connect to Internet. The connection used to work fine few month ago. It doesn't work neither from my application that should download RSS feed nor from internet browser. I am connecting using a 3G USB.

The web page at www.google.com might be temporary down or may be moved permantly to a new web addresss.

Note that I checked that:
- GSM modem support is included 
- I gived the INTERNET authorisation to my application
- I don't use any proxy to connect to the internet
- The 3G icon in displayed on top of the screen
- I activated data roaming

None of these helped solving the issue.

Recently I added to network interface to my computer. A wired connection and VirtualBox network card.

Could you please help me finding a solution? I suspect that my AVD is connected to a wrong interface that doesn't provide an Internet Connection.

Where Can I find any trace/log file that helps tracking this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt session in your windows machine

issue the following command to connect to emulator:

> adb -e shell

in emulator shell issu the command:

> ifconfig eth0

and you will get the ip address of emulator and the information if it's running.

You can also use the command:

> ping ipaddress

to check connectivity to a specific ip address.

Depending on the result from the above commands, as you are in a linux shell, you may look for general linux help on network commands the check and verify connectivity.

good luck.